# finding a file name from a substring

Tags: python, string, file

I have a list of my filenames that I've saved as follows:

```
filelist = os.listdir(mypath)
```

Now, suppose one of my files is something like "`KRAS_P01446_3GFT_SOMETHING_SOMETHING.txt`".

However, all I know ahead of time is that I have a file called "`KRAS_P01446_3GFT_*`". How can I get the full file name from file list using just "`KRAS_P01446_3GFT_*`"?

As a simpler example, I've made the following:

```
mylist = ["hi_there", "bye_there","hello_there"]
```

Suppose I had the string `"hi"`. How would I make it return `mylist[0] = "hi_there"`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you could just use the `glob` module:

```
import glob
import os
print '\n'.join(glob.iglob(os.path.join(mypath, "KRAS_P01446_3GFT_*")))
```

Do this *instead* of `os.listdir`.

The second example seems tenuously related to the first ([X-Y problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)?), but here's an implementation:

```
mylist = ["hi_there", "bye_there","hello_there"]
print '\n'.join(s for s in mylist if s.startswith("hi"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "give me all filenames starting with some prefix", then this is simple:

```
[fname for fname in mylist if fname.startswith('hi')]
```

If you mean something more complex--for example, patterns like "some_*_file" matching "some_good_file" and "some_bad_file", then look at the regex module.

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = ["hi_there", "bye_there","hello_there"]
partial = "hi"
[fullname for fullname in mylist if fullname.startswith(partial)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list is not very big, you can do a per item check like this.

```
def findMatchingFile (fileList, stringToMatch) :
    listOfMatchingFiles = []

    for file in fileList:
        if file.startswith(stringToMatch):
            listOfMatchingFiles.append(file)

    return listOfMatchingFiles
```

There are more "pythonic" way of doing this, but I prefer this as it is more readable.

Comment: May be, may be not. Depends on, if the person asking knows what a generator is and how yield works. By my experience that is something  few people know.